# Given $\frac{\sin(A - B)}{\sin(A+B)} = \frac57$, show $\tan A = 6 \tan B$

Tags: trigonometry

I can expand the sine using compound angle formula but then I can't continue to make it become a tangent.

Comment: Hint: divide everything by $\cos A \cos B$.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @labbhattacharjee HINT: Since
$$
\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\frac{\sin(A)\cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)}{\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)}=\frac{5}{7}    \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
**Using Componendo & Dividendo**
Now, is easy to prove "Componendo & Dividendo":
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \ \Rightarrow \frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d} 
$$
Then 
$$
\frac{2\sin(A)\cos(B)}{-2\cos(A)\sin(B)} = \frac{12}{-2} \Rightarrow \frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)} = 6\frac{\sin(B)}{\cos(B)}
$$
Which gives $\tan(A)=6\tan(B)$ as disered.

**Without Componendo & Dividendo** Equation (1) above gives
$$
7\left(\sin(A)\cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)\right)= 5\left(\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)\right)
$$
wich reduces to
$$
2\sin(A)\cos(B)=12\sin(B)\cos(A)
$$
arranging terms this is the same as 
$$
\frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)} = 6\frac{\sin(B)}{\cos(B)}
$$
and again this gives $\tan(A)=6\tan(B)$.

Comment: I don't really understand the `Componendo & Dividendo` method , is there a simpler method

Comment: Yes sure. Give me 5 min to edit my answer then.

Comment: @user2650277 Is now better ?

Comment: @user2650277 The first method is actually pretty simple. If you don't understand something, ask for clarification. Alonso is employing the implication $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\Rightarrow\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$ using $a=\sin(A-B)$ and $b=\sin(A+B)$ (the expanded-out versions) and $c=5$, $d=7$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B\pm \cos A\sin B$$

Then apply Componendo & Dividendo

Comment: I already use this for the numerator and denominator , the `Componendo & Dividendo` is the hard part for me

Comment: @user2650277, Not sure why? Then separate out $\sin A\cos B, \cos A\sin B$

Answer (score 1):

Use the trigonometric identities:
$$\tan A+\tan B=\frac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos A\cos B}, \quad \tan A-\tan B=\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\cos A\cos B},$$
from which you deduce:
$$\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{\tan A+\tan B}=\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\frac 57,$$
whence 
$$7(\tan A-\tan B)=5(\tan A+\tan B)\iff 2\tan A=12\tan B.$$